# Azure function trigger Twice

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

Hello I have a problem about azure functions.
I have a blob trigger function on azure. The problem is when i try to upload a file to container using by SFTP my function fires twice but if manually upload my file on azure its getting only one trigger.
Note : Files comes as with the same name for each trigger not comes with the filepart.
Is there any solution about that?. Sharing the logs below.
Please help me to fix that issue.

Azure Monitoring log
[image]

I tried to decrease file size to 1kb if the issue about file size but didn't work
[FixedDelayRetry(0, "00:00:10")] tried add this attribute and didn't work.

Comment: Update : Tried the upload file with powershell and same issue.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806089/azure-event-grid-blob-storage-prevent-double-blob-created-events and look at the reference in the comment too but not sure if that applies to SFTP and Powershell.  I am guessing it is due to file being created triggering once and then after the upload completing triggering again.  Look for any settings that might affect this.

Comment: Yes I checked the content lengths but in anyway content length comes as same for both trigger.

Comment: Might need to open Azure support request to have them look at.

Comment: I already did waiting for their response also thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i got response from Azure support that issue related with microsoft and they tell fix it as soon as possible. The issue exactly appear when you use Eventgrid as source if you remove it then function only fires once but in this scenario latency increasing on your function. Anyway if you skip this issue till fixed you need to remove that.
[image]

Edit : Issue solved by Azure support.